# Failed to lookup view

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Hi I'm trying to work with Express 3 using handlebars. But I am unable to "lookup the view" I am stuck with this error.

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "500" in views directory
"d:\projects\meadowlark\site\views"    at EventEmitter.app.render
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:519:17)
at ServerResponse.res.render
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:904:7)
at d:\projects\meadowlark\site\meadowlark.js:29:7    at
Layer.handle_error
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:58:5)
at trim_prefix
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:269:13)
at
d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:238:9
at Function.proto.process_params
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:313:12)
at
d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:229:12
at Function.match_layer
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:296:3)
at next
(d:\projects\meadowlark\site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:190:10)
```

Its really strange for me. Can anyone explain this issue to me how can I solve it?

My js code is as follows:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// set up handlebars view engine
var handlebars = require('express3-handlebars')
.create({ defaultLayout:'main' });
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine);
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.set('port',process.env.port || 3000);

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render('home');
    });

    app.get('/about', function(req, res) {
        res.render('about');
    });

// 404 catch-all handler (middleware)
    app.use(function(req, res, next){
        res.status(404);
        res.render('404');
    });

// 500 error handler (middleware)
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
        console.error(err.stack);
        res.status(500);
        res.render('500');
    });

app.listen(app.get('port'),function(){
    console.log('Express started on http://localhost: '+ app.get('port') + " Press CTRL+C to terminate.");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what the issue here is, remember this setup of app.js from an O'Reilly book ("Web Development with Node & Express").
Here's what the author fails to clarify:

If you have your `.handlebars` template files in `views/layouts/`, structure your view engine setup like this:

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var handlebars = require('express-handlebars'); // 'express3-handlebars' has been deprecated
var app = express();

// Set up handlebars view engine
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views/layouts/'));
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

Note that you will need the `var path = require('path');` in order to set 'views' to the filepath `views/layouts/`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your files: home.handlebars, about.handlebars, 404.handlebars, 500.handlebars and main.handlebars **don't have hidden extensions**. Like this: home.handlebars.html, about.handlebars.html, 404.handlebars.html, 500.handlebars.html, and main.handlebars.html.

**If they do, removing those extensions and using only the .handlebars extension should resolve the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

If you read the error, it clearly tells you that you are missing a 500 view template in your template directory. I'm not sure what your directory structure you have, but place a `500.handlebars` file in the same directory the `404.handlebars` file is. Should be somewhere in the `views/` or `views/layouts` directory.